# How to fix slideshow?

Tags: javascript, html, carousel, bootstrap-5, card

I'm trying to have a slideshow (carousel) of cards on my index.html.
The code I currently have presents all five cards vertically stacked, with clickable arrows that don't do anything. Anyone know how to make it so one card is shown at a time and can be clicked on to the next?

```
<div id="carouselExample" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="card active" style="width: 12rem;">
            <img src="https://static.americasbestracing.net/s3fs-public/styles/large/public/reylu-gutierrez.jpg?KHONSa1SS2GQbZtqmIed8QZzxaE.XX.4&itok=AKl_nQxN" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Reylu Gutierrez.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card" style="width: 12rem;">
            <img src="https://www.nyra.com/uploads/profile-images/eric-cancel.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Eric Cancel.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card" style="width: 12rem;">
            <img src="https://www.nyra.com/uploads/profile-images/manuel-franco.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Manuel Franco.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card" style="width: 12rem;">
            <img src="https://www.nyra.com/uploads/profile-images/joel-rosario.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Joel Rosario.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card" style="width: 12rem;">
            <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/43429236045_546119af43_b.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Andre Worrie.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExample" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExample" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

I have the CSS and JS sources. My js file has these lines

```
const myCarouselElement = document.querySelector('#myCarousel')

const carousel = new bootstrap.Carousel(myCarouselElement, {
  interval: 2000,
  touch: false
})
```

Console log says bootstrap is not defined in the const carousel line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay in bootstrap you must follow template provide ,see this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/carousel/

you forget take class= "carousel-item"

so like this

```
<div class="card carousel-item " style="width: 12rem;">
            <img src="https://www.nyra.com/uploads/profile-images/joel-rosario.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Joel Rosario.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I knew it would be something simple that I was missing.